# Merge rasters with different extents and pixel sizes

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

Is there a way to merge rasters with different extents and pixel sizes, or change the extent and pixel sizes of the rasters so that they are equal when I merge them? Ideally in QGIS.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy way to do this is to use the Build Virtual Raster tool, in the Processing toolbox. You can choose the resolution and extent (as well as projection) of the virtual raster. If needed you can then save the virtual raster out to disk as it's own raster.